# How to initialize a private static set in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a private set member with the following header declaration

```
class foo
{
    private:
        static std::set<int> _mySet;
};
```

How can I use _mySet in my source file? I have tried to initialize it but these didn't work:

```
std::set<int> foo::_mySet{};  //  error: qualified-id in declaration before ‘{’ token
foo::_mySet = std::set<int>();  // error "...is private within this context"
```

Comment: What's the syntax error on the first line?

Comment: The first variant should have worked. Though it could've been shorter `std::set<int> foo::_mySet{};`. And with C++17 there is no need for out of class definition at all, just make it inline. What was the error you've got?

Comment: Can you post copy-pasted error the compiler returns? I've tried the first variant and it compiled with no errors on my machine (C++11, gcc 7.3.0).

Comment: Sounds like you need a member function that will be able to access the private data member.

Comment: After error got edited-in to the question: Are you sure you initialize it outside of any function and after you include the header file with your class?

Comment: Ron: When I try to access the static set in a member function I get an undefined reference error.

Comment: @fadiak You are confusing the storage duration with the (external) visibility.

Comment: Jacek Ślimok : I initialize it inside main(). The header was included

Comment: Initialization should be outside of the functions. You should've posted complete example code...

Comment: @VTT: Thanks. now it works :)

Answer (score 1):

This compiles just fine in VS2017 CE

*Foo.h*

```
#pragma once

#include <set>

class Foo {
private:
    static std::set<int> mySet_;

public:
    Foo() = default;

    static std::set<int> getSet() {
        return mySet_;
    }

    static void addToSet( int val ) {
        mySet_.insert( val );
    }
};
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
#include "Foo.h"

std::set<int> Foo::mySet_{};
```

If you try to do this:

```
static std::set<int> mySet_ = {};
// or
static std::set<int> mySet_{};
```

In the header file Visual Studio gives the suggestion that `a member with an in-class initializer must be const`

So if we change this to `const`

```
static const std::set<int> mySet_ = {};
// or
static const std::set<int> mySet{};
```

Visual Studio complains that `a member of type "const std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int>>" cannot have an in-class initializer`

I hope this helps to clarify how the compiler interprets these declarations - definitions and initializations.